# Flutter Provider: How to notify a model that a change happened on a model it contains?

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management, flutter-provider

I'm starting to learn Flutter/Dart by building a simple Todo app using Provider, and I've run into a state management issue. To be clear, the code I've written works, but it seems... wrong. I can't find any examples that resemble my case enough for me to understand what the correct way to approach the issue is.

[This is what the app looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUP61.png)

It's a grocery list divided by sections ("Frozen", "Fruits and Veggies"). Every *section* has multiple items, and displays a "x of y completed" progress indicator. Every *item* "completes" when it is pressed.

The`GroceryItemModel` looks like this:

```
class GroceryItemModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  final String name;

  bool _completed = false;

  GroceryItemModel(this.name);

  bool get completed => _completed;

  void complete() {
    _completed = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

And I use it in the `GroceryItem` widget like so:

```
class GroceryItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final GroceryItemModel model;

  GroceryItem(this.model);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
        value: model,
        child: Consumer<GroceryItemModel>(builder: (context, groceryItem, child) {
          return ListTile(
              title: Text(groceryItem.name),
              leading: groceryItem.completed ? Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.green) : Icon(Icons.radio_button_unchecked)
              onTap: () => groceryItem.complete();
        })
    );
  }
}
```

The next step I want is to include multiple *items* in a *section*, which tracks completeness based on how many items are completed.

The `GroceryListSectionModel` looks like this:

```
class GroceryListSectionModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  final String name;
  List<GroceryItemModel> items;

  GroceryListSectionModel(this.name, [items]) {
    this.items = items == null ? [] : items;

    // THIS RIGHT HERE IS WHERE IT GETS WEIRD
    items.forEach((item) {
      item.addListener(notifyListeners);
    });
    // END WEIRD
  }

  int itemCount() => items.length;
  int completedItemCount() => items.where((item) => item.completed).length;
}
```

And I use it in the `GroceryListSection` widget like so:

```
class GroceryListSection extends StatelessWidget {
  final GroceryListSectionModel model;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;

  GroceryListSection(this.model, this.onChanged);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: model,
      child: Consumer<GroceryListSectionModel>(
        builder: (context, groceryListSection, child) {
          return Container(
              child: ExpansionTile(
                  title: Text(model.name),
                  subtitle: Text("${groceryListSection.completedItemCount()} of ${groceryListSection.itemCount()} completed"),
                  children: groceryListSection.items.map((groceryItemModel) =>
                      GroceryItem(groceryItemModel)).toList()
              )
          );
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**The Problems:**

1. It seems weird to have a `ChangeNotifierProvider` and a `Consumer` in both Widgets. None of the examples I've seen do that.
2. It's *definitely* wrong to have the `GroceryListSectionModel` listening to changes on all the `GroceryItemModels` for changes to propagate back up the tree. I don't see how that can scale right.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this ist not a nested Provider, but i think in your example it is the better way..

only one ChangeNotifierProvider per `section ("Frozen", "Fruits and Veggies")` is defined

the `complete()` function from a `ItemModel` is in the `GroceryListSectionModel()` and with the parameter from the current List Index

```
class GroceryListSection extends StatelessWidget {
  final GroceryListSectionModel model;
 // final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;

  GroceryListSection(this.model);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new ChangeNotifierProvider<GroceryListSectionModel>(
        create: (context) => GroceryListSectionModel(model.name, model.items),
        child: new Consumer<GroceryListSectionModel>(
        builder: (context, groceryListSection, child) {
          return Container(
              child: ExpansionTile(
                  title: Text(model.name),
                  subtitle: Text("${groceryListSection.completedItemCount()} of ${groceryListSection.itemCount()} completed"),
                  children: groceryListSection.items.asMap().map((i, groceryItemModel) => MapEntry(i, GroceryItem(groceryItemModel, i))).values.toList()
              )
          );
        }
      )
    );
  }
}

class GroceryItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final GroceryItemModel model;
  final int index;

  GroceryItem(this.model, this.index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(model.name),
      leading: model.completed ? Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.green) : Icon(Icons.radio_button_unchecked),
      onTap: () => Provider.of<GroceryListSectionModel>(context, listen: false).complete(index),
    );

  }
}

class GroceryListSectionModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  String name;
  List<GroceryItemModel> items;

  GroceryListSectionModel(this.name, [items]) {
    this.items = items == null ? [] : items;
  }

  int itemCount() => items.length;
  int completedItemCount() => items.where((item) => item.completed).length;

  // complete Void with index from List items
  void complete(int index) {
    this.items[index].completed = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}

// normal Model without ChangeNotifier
class GroceryItemModel {
  final String name;
  bool completed = false;

  GroceryItemModel({this.name, completed}) {
    this.completed = completed == null ? false : completed;
  }

}
```